# Placing a canvas element in background to a html table

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I'm trying to place a canvas element as background of a html table.

The idea is to have a table and play animations with canvas in the background.

What happens is, if I try:

```
<canvas width="300" height="300">
    <table class="table" id="game"></table>
</canvas>
```

the canvas eats the table, and I can't get it to appear.

If I try the opposite and place the canvas inside the table, I can't get a good position, the canvas just moves to the side.

My idea is to center the canvas, and center the table in the center of the canvas. Be aware the table size can change with javascript. It's sufficient if the canvas gets the same width/height as the table.

Answer (score 3):

Use separate sibling elements rather than parent-child relationship.

```
<canvas></canvas>
<table></table>
```

Absolute easiest way is to absolutely position them, size them (or grab the size of the table and change the size of the canvas) and use `z-index` to stack them.

```
canvas,
table {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

canvas {
  z-index: 1;
}
table {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

You'll probably have to be slightly smarter if the table and canvas are to change size.